# dynamically add comboboxes to flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, combobox, dynamic-programming, numericupdown, flowlayoutpanel

I'm  working on a project for school but I'm stuck at this moment.
I want to dynamically add comboboxes to my flowlayoutpanel which depends of the value of a numeric up and down.

So if the numeric up down value is 2 that 2 comboboxes are dynamically made, but I can't really figure how to do this, this is what I was thinking of.

```
public partial class ...Form: Form
{
    ComboBox[] cbChoices;

    private void nudGuests_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowPanel.Controls.Clear();

        for (int i = 1; i < nudGuests.Value; i++)
        {
            cbChoices[i] = new ComboBox();
            flowPanel.Controls.Add(cbChoices[i]);
        }
    }
 }
```

but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.

Firstly, your cbChoices array is not initialzed, so do `cbChoices = new ComboBoxnudGuests.Value;

Secondly, C# uses 0-indexing (starts counting arrays at the 0th element instead of the 1st), so use `for (int i = 0 ....)`

Thirdly, do you really need the array of ComboBoxes or can you just add them without storing them?

This should point you in the right direction.